# How to fix "Cannot read property '...' of undefined" when calling angular service method inside template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-ng-if

I created a new service in my project and I added some functions to it.
When I tried to call a service function from my component template I got this error "Cannot read property 'isCompanyEligible' of undefined"

I tried to create new function inside my component and assign the service function to it but I got the same error.

This is my service:

```
import { FinancialHealth } from 'src/app/shared/models/financial-health';
import { LocalStoreService } from 'src/app/shared/services/local-store.service';
import {Application} from './../models/application';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateParserFormatterService} from './ngb-date-parser-formatter.service ';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EligibilityService {
  application: Application;
  activityAreas = [];
  areasEligibility = [];
  legalForms = [];
  jobPositions = [];
  constructor(
    private ls: LocalStoreService,
    private dateService: NgbDateParserFormatterService

  ) {
    this.application = this.ls.getItem('application');
    const {
      activity_areas,
      legal_forms,
      job_positions,
      areas_eligiblity
    } =
    this.ls.getItem('shared_data').data;
    this.activityAreas = activity_areas;
    this.legalForms = legal_forms;
    this.jobPositions = job_positions.filter(job => job.is_management_position ==
      1);
    this.areasEligibility = areas_eligiblity;
  }

  public isCompanyEligible(application ? ) {
    if (application) {
      this.application = application;
    }
    if (!this.application || (!this.application.company)) {
      return null;
    }
    const company = this.application.company;
    let age;
    if (typeof this.application.company.established_at == 'object') {
      const date =
        this.dateService.format(this.application.company.established_at);
      age = this.getAge(date);
    } else {
      age = this.getAge(company.established_at)
    }
    return this.legalForms.includes(company.legal_form) && (age >= 2 && age <=
      5);
  }

  growthRate(firstYear, secondYear) {
    if (!firstYear || !secondYear) {
      return 0;
    }
    return Math.round(((secondYear - firstYear) / firstYear) * 100);
  }
}
```

This is my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomValidators } from 'ng2-validation';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { DataLayerService } from 'src/app/shared/services/data-layer.service';
import { BreadcrumbService } from '../../../shared/services/breadcrumb.service';
import { EligibilityService } from 'src/app/shared/services/eligibility.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-sommaire',
  templateUrl: './sommaire.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sommaire.component.scss']
})
export class SommaireFormComponent implements OnInit {
  formBasic: FormGroup;
  loading: boolean;
  radioGroup: FormGroup;
  sharedData: any;
  isValid: Boolean = false;
  application: any;
  breadcrumb: { label: string; route: string; }[];
  title: String = 'Sommaire';
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private ls: LocalStoreService,
    private appService: ApplicationService,
    private data: BreadcrumbService,
    public eligibility: EligibilityService
  ) { }

}
```

This is my HTML template:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <i *ngIf="eligibility.isCompanyEligible()" class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-circle large-success"></i>
  <i *ngIf="eligibility.isCompanyEligible() === false" class="icon ion-ios-close-circle large-danger"></i>
  <i *ngIf="eligibility.isCompanyEligible() == null" class="icon ion-md-alert large-warning"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I think it has something to do with the modules? like if you have multiple modules you might get this issue when the template in a module where service can't access

Answer (score 0):

Anything marked as `private` cannot be accessed by the component's template either. (Private members can be accessed when using JIT, such as at development time, but not when using AOT, such as for production.)

Actually, best practice is to wrap any service properties/methods in a component property/method and have the template bind to/call the component's property or method to access the service data.

Something like this:

```
   get isCompanyEligible(): boolean {
      return this.eligibility.isCompanyEligible();
   }
```

and use it in your template: - `<i *ngIf="isCompanyEligible()"`

**OR**

Make the `EligibilityService` injection public in `constructor` of component, to access inside template:

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private ls: LocalStoreService,
    private appService: ApplicationService,
    private data: BreadcrumbService,
    public eligibility: EligibilityService
  ) { }
```

Comment: Sorry your solution doesn't resolve my problem @nircraft

Comment: Can you update your HTML to use the component method as mentioned in first solution? What error do you see? Also i see in your code `public isCompanyEligible(application ? ) {` expects a parameter, which you are not passing from HTML and that's why `null` is returned from your service method

Comment: I tried it I removed the parameter but i still get the same error @nircraft

Comment: @SelmiMed, see your code `if (application) {
      this.application = application;
    }
    if (!this.application || (!this.application.company)) {
      return null;
    }` 
this will return null if there is no application passed to the service method. Can you share the updated code at stackblitz or here so that i can see what you are doing

Comment: application is an optional parameter (application?) . I update just the return statment to false nd i got  the same error                          
 if (application) { this.application = application; } if (!this.application || (!this.application.company)) { return null; } .